# Catching thrown errors with SinonJS

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, should.js

I've got a method that may throw an Error, but I'm having trouble writing a SinonJS/Mocha/Should unit test case for this condition.

Sample function under test:

```
function testError(value) {
  if (!value) {
    throw new Error('No value');
    return false;
  }
};
```

Sample test:

```
describe('#testError', function() {
  it('throws an error', function() {
    var spy = sinon.spy(testError);
    testError(false);
    spy.threw().should.be.true();
  });
});
```

This outputs:

```
  #testError
    1) throws an error


  0 passing (11ms)
  1 failing

  1) #testError throws an error:
     Error: No value
      at testError (tests/unit/js/test-error.js:6:14)
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/unit/js/test-error.js:14:6)
```

I was expecting Sinon to catch the Error and allow me to spy on the throw, but it seems to fail the test instead. Any ideas?

I referred to [Don't sinon.js spys catch errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752369/dont-sinon-js-spys-catch-errors) but the only solution there is to use `expect`. I'd prefer to keep with a single assertion library if possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears that this works inside a `try`/`catch`:

```
function foo() { throw new Error("hey!"); }
var fooSpy = sinon.spy(foo);
try {
  fooSpy();
} catch (e) {
  // pass
}
assert(fooSpy.threw());
```

Note that you have to call `fooSpy`, *not* `foo` itself.

But also note that `.should.be.true()` is *not* part of Sinon, so you're probably already using Chai or a similar library, in which case the `expect(foo).to.have.thrown()` or `assert.throws(foo, someError)` syntax seems much nicer.

**Update:** If you're using ShouldJS, looks like you can use [`should.throws`](https://shouldjs.github.io/#should-throws). I still think this is nicer than using the Sinon version for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, @nrabinowitz. Looks like ```should.throws``` might be the ticket. See my revised answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**Revised**

Following @nrabinowitz's helpful advice, here's a solution that uses `should.throws`. This avoids using `Sinon.spy` altogether.

```
describe('#testError', function() {
  it('throws an error', function() {
    should.throws(function() {
      testError(false);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That doesn't do what you think. `stub.throws()` is pre-programming behavior for the stub, not asserting that it was called. Stubs do *not* call the underlying function - try this out with another function that does not throw, and you'll see the behavior unchanged.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Using ```stub``` was a false positive. I think using ```should.throws``` and calling the actual function under test works. And avoids using Sinon entirely. See my revised answer.

Answer (score -2):

```js
            const bootstrap = async anyParam => {
                if(!anyParam){
                    throw new Error('test')
                }

                await anyParam()
            }

            const spy = sinon.spy(bootstrap)

            try {
                await spy();
            } catch (e) {
                expect(e.message).to.be.equal('test')
                spy.called = false
            }

            expect(spy.called).to.be.equal(false);
```