# Catching thrown errors with SinonJS, UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, async-await, mocha.js, sinon

I have the following async function that checks the returned value from a promise and I having trouble writing

```
    async function fetchData(pageLocation) {
       const data = await 
       apiService.fetchPage(pageLocation);
       if (!data || !data.mapping) {
          const error = new Error(`Unknown channel ${pageLocation}`);
          error.code = 404;
          throw (error);
       }
       return data.mapping;
     }
```

---

Test case

```
describe.only('fetchData', () => {
    let fetchPage;
    beforeEach(() => {
        fetchPage = 
           sinon.stub().returns(Promise.resolve(mockMapping));
        csfPageService.__set__({
            apiService: {
                fetchPage,
            },
        });
    });

it('should throw an error when there is no available Data', () => {
   channeData', async function() {
        const fetchChannelSectionData = pageService.__get__('fetchData');
        expect(async () => { await fetchData('pageLocation'); }).to.throw();
        expect(fetchPage).to.be.calledWith('pageLocation');
        console.log('----------------------2');
    });
```

What causing the main issue is having an async function and a promise I am able to use the same approach when it is not an async function and there is no await I have looked into the following links

- [Catching thrown errors with SinonJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893279/catching-thrown-errors-with-sinonjs)
- https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw
  [enter link description here](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/655)

but I haven't been successful 
please advise on how should this be done ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one of the reasons I don't like async, await, they are just syntactic sugar over promises, but they uses normal/sync semantics but just in appearance.
Async functions never throws, no matter how bad is the error you throw inside it, they will just return a rejected promise. In your case, your function is not throwing at all, it is returning a rejected promise, and you are not attaching any catch hanlder to that promise, hence the warning. When you use async function or promises, forget about normal handling of errors, promises catches any error automatically and encapsulates them on a rejected promise.

So, in your case the correc way of doing this will vary depending on your testing framework, but it could be something like this:

```
it('should throw an error when there is no available Data', () => {
   channeData', async function() {
        const fetchChannelSectionData = pageService.__get__('fetchData');
        fetchData('pageLocation').catch(err => {
            expect(err).to.be.an.error();
            expect(fetchPage).to.be.calledWith('pageLocation');
            console.log('----------------------2');
        })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I had to modify it a bit as I am using sinon as in `expect(err).to.throw();`  but it passes the test now with an error 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: expected [Error: Unknown channel pageLocation] to be a function' do you know what to do in this case ?

Comment: The tricky part about promises, and therefore async functions, is that they automatically catch any error, so your code is failing at a different level, it's being automatically caught and you are not attaching any catch to that failed promise. If you share a gist with your current code I can take a look at it